# calculation of money account in a bank in recursive

Tags: javascript, java, recursion

```
public static double capitalAfterYearsRecursive(double K0, int n, double i,double R) {
    double K1;
    if(n < 0)
    {   
        return K0;
    }
    else
    return capitalAfterYearsRecursive(K0, n-1 ,i ,R)*(i+1);
}
```

So guys i need your help, it doesnt show up the correct balance :/

```
 K0 start capital
 n runtime (years)
 i interest rate
 R yearly rate
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: can you add example of your parameter data that you want to calculate, and expected result ?

Comment: Why are you passing in both an "interest rate" and a "yearly rate"?  What are these that they're independent?  You never use **R** in your calculations.

Comment: K0 = 5054.51
n = 37
i = 0.009
R = 353.82

excpected : 22494.208213
was : 7041.28966

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static double capitalAfterYearsRecursive(double K0, int n, double i,double R) {

    //double K1;
    if(n <= 0)
    {   
        return K0;
    }
    else
    return capitalAfterYearsRecursive(K0, n-1 ,i ,R)*(i+1)+R;
}
```

Ok, the problem was, i had to add the **+R**

Comment: so select your own anwser as the correct anwser.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your initial problem is that base condition.  You run the recursion back to year -1, rather than year 0.  How about

```
if (n <= 0)
```

...

Try your code with a time period of 0: your result should be the original principal.